# Problems in backups after changed the passwords

Tags: advantage-database-server

Here I am with another problem with the backups.

Since my company decided to change the passwords of all of our clients
due security issues, we got a problem with the backups.

Our application server is in charged to make the backups of the databases,
by running the sp_backupdatabase procedure.

Before we changed the password, the databases were working with 2
different passwords: one for the clients, and the other for all of
us, the developers.

Making the backups in this scenario was not a problem.

But now that we changed the passwords, some problems came out.

Once the sp_backupdatabase has made the backup (in our application server),
the next step we do is link all of the tables to the data dictionary.
We do this by connecting to the data dictionary that has just been created with
the sp_backupdatabase, but, alas, the connection fails, and advantage throws me
a message, telling me the either user or the password is incorrect.

The next thing I did, was a little test.
I created a simple database with three tables. I set the next password to the database:

PASSWORD (Clever, ah?)

Next, I executed the sp_BackupDataBase procedure to create the backup.
I opened the data dictionary of the backup, and it gave me no problem.
After that, I executed the sp_restoreDataBase, and everything was just fine.

And that's when I changed the password again, with PASSWORD1.
I did the same procedure, and had success.

But, when I changed the password a third time (let's say PASSWORD2),
when I tried to open the backup (before running sp_restoreDataBase) with
that password, Advantage told me the user or the password was incorrect.

After that (again), I changed to the previous password (PASSWORD1), and
the backup opened just fine. But, by changing to the first password (PASSWORD),
It didn't open.

Well, I had to describe you this very well, because I don't know what's happening.
Is there a problem with advantage that involves the backups and the fact of changing passwords?

I really hope that you can help me, because this is a real problem for our company.

Thank you very much in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

This may have been a bug that was fixed.  Try out the latest 10.1 server (currently 10.10.0.28)

[ADS 10.10.0.28](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?Key=20&Release=16&Product=25)

Check under the 10.10.0.17 release notes for number 10

> 1. Fixed a 7078 error when restoring a database with a different
>      password than the current connection to the database uses.